# Ubuntu freezes randomly - nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, freeze

I have a problem on my Ubuntu.

I don't know why, but my Ubuntu always freezes after sometime using the computer, no matter what I'm doing, web browsing, editing a .txt file, listening to some music, playing a game, it always freezes.

It only stops when i use nvidia proprietary driver, do you guys know why this happen?

Another thing that happens, when I'm using the open source driver from xorg, I've better performance, hardware acceleration works fine, but in another way, when I'm using nvidia driver, my hardware acceleration doesn't work very well.

This happens in multiplies distros, in `Linux Mint 18.2`, `Linux Mint 18.3`, `Ubuntu 12.04`, `Ubuntu 14.04`, `Ubuntu Gnome 14.04`, `Xubuntu 14.04`, `Ubuntu 17.10`, `Elementary OS`, `Fedora 27`.

GPU: NVIDIA GTX 660 from ZOTAC.

Comment: This unfortunately may never be sufficiently answered. :(